# Can js wait until XHR fully loaded in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, xmlhttprequest

I am noob designing for website HTML with bootstrap

I found HTML does not support html include, so I googled and found awesome js which makes me manage header.html separetely and import to main html

I use another js which is needed at header.html

And what I found is that the js starts before
header.html XHR fully finished so it didnt apply to the imported header.html

So here I need to ask is that
is there any ways I can use for js to wait until XHR which is called from another js fully loded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function similar to `$.ready` in jQuery to call a function when the page is finished loading, I recommend this simple `waitUntilReady` function over jQuery though:

```html
<script>

  const checkElement = () => console.log(
    'div#checkIfLoaded:',
    document.getElementById('checkIfLoaded')
  );
  
  const waitUntilReady = (fn) => document.readyState === 'complete'
    // fire immediately if document ready
    ? fn()
    // otherwise fire on DOMContentLoaded
    : window.addEventListener(
        'DOMContentLoaded', 
        fn
    );
  
  // doesn't exist yet
  checkElement();
  
  // will wait until the page is loaded
  waitUntilReady(checkElement);
  
</script>
<div id="checkIfLoaded"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the most important concept you need to understand is async and sync code.
You can do something like this.

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // Do something
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "another.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

I won't recommend this approach as there's a lot of better and easy option to do that: [Link](https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/)